# Во всей таблице показать список ячеек в кодировке latin1_swedish_ci

Tags: mysql

Не получается сделать запрос, чтобы показать все строки в ячейке `latin1_swedish_ci`.
И запрос чтобы переопределить кодировку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP ? по аналогии:

```
mysql_query(”SET NAMES ‘utf8′”);
mysql_query(”SET collation_connection=’utf8_general_ci’”);
mysql_query(”SET collation_server=’utf8_general_ci’”);
mysql_query(”SET character_set_client=’utf8′”);
mysql_query(”SET character_set_connection=’utf8′”);
mysql_query(”SET character_set_results=’utf8′”);
mysql_query(”SET character_set_server=’utf8′”);
```